# How to test app on Oreo version if no virtualization available

Tags: android, testing, sdk, android-emulator, android-virtual-device

I have no virtualization on my Laptop because it has `AMD A6-5200` processor. I searched over the net and get to know that I can test app if I make arm base emulator device. But there is no arm based device available In the Other Images `tab` in Virtual Device Configuration.

So my question is how to test my app on Oreo.

Comment: [Android Oreo 测试专区](http://wetest.qq.com/cloud/help/AndroidOreo)

Comment: @sanemars I can't understand chinese

Comment: 1stly, it looks like your CPU **does** support hardware virtualization. It is called `AMD-V ` for AMD CPUs. But it is not supported by Android studio emulator on Windows (while is supported on Linux). So there are 5 and only simple solutions: 1) switch to Linux. 2) Switch to another development machine. 3) don't test on Oreo. 4) Find other emulator (Genymotion themes to support Oreo already 5) **The correct one** - Buy a Oreo-powered real device.

Comment: @VladMatvienko thanks for suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

You can Try The Other virtual Machine Like [Genymotion](https://www.genymotion.com/)

Genymotion [Download](https://www.genymotion.com/fun-zone/)